# How can I keep my original player scale when parented to another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player movement script attached to my player object, and a separate script attached to a different object which references my player and then parents it to that said object.

When I enter the trigger of the specific object, my player scale reduces from (1, 1, 1) to like (0.9, 0.88, 0.98) and never reverts back, even after exiting trigger.

I have tried to add a line of code in the trigger to force my scale to remain the same with Vector3 but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            Player.transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. According to Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html) you can try using the lossyScale:

> The global scale of the object (Read Only).
>
> **Please note that if you have a parent transform with scale and a child
> that is arbitrarily rotated, the scale will be skewed. Thus scale can
> not be represented correctly in a 3 component vector but only a 3x3
> matrix.** Such a representation is quite inconvenient to work with
> however. lossyScale is a convenience property that attempts to match
> the actual world scale as much as it can. If your objects are not
> skewed the value will be completely correct and most likely the value
> will not be very different if it contains skew too.

Also simply exiting the trigger is not doing anything. You should detach from parent transform `OnTriggerExit` :

```
Player.transform.parent = null;
```

2. You can change your Player moment script to instead follow your trigger transform position without changing your Player transform parent. This way your Player scale won't be affected.

Comment: I currently do have player.transform.parent = null; on my triggerExit, however the scale remains the same.

Comment: You can try setting the scale to Vector3(1, 1, 1) OnTriggerExit next line after removing the parent.

Comment: Yeah so I had this previously: Player.transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 1); but it makes my character increase in size by like x5. Making the vector (0,0,0) fixes that issue, but the scale is still like (0.99, 0.25, 0.98)

Comment: += adds to a Vector. Use `Player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);`

Comment: And make sure your Player is detached from the parent

Comment: Yeah sorry the + was a typo, but that part now works. The main issue though is the scale reduction whilst still on the parented object. Trying that same line of code makes my player bounce like crazy while parented. Is there a way to transform scale without using local? Maybe that's the issue